# Google App Engine optimistic concurrency

Tags: database, google-app-engine

I'm reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview) for Google App Engine and stumbled upon something that I don't quite understand:

> The Datastore uses optimistic concurrency to manage transactions. When
>   two or more application instances try to change the same entity group
>   at the same time (either by updating existing entities or by creating
>   new ones), the first application to commit its changes will succeed
>   and all others will fail on commit. These other applications can then
>   try their transactions again to apply them to the updated data. Note
>   that because the Datastore works this way, using entity groups limits
>   the number of concurrent writes you can do to any entity in a given
>   group.

Does this mean that if two different users from two different devices try to modify the same object, only one of them will succeed? Is this typical database behavior, or just a GAE limitation? How do other databases usually handle such situations, where two or more users try to modify the same object?

And what does it mean by the fact that when two or more application instances try to create new entities, only one will succeed. Am I understanding that wrong? No two application instances can add a new object to the same table?

Comment: pay attention to the design of your code: putting several entries in the same entity group make queries faster but has several limitations to the concurrency problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I can't speak for document databases like MongoDB and the like (aka NoSQL), I can tell you that relational databases would only allow one *operation* to take effect. However, this comes down to what the operations *are*.

For example, say two users tried to modify the same object. If their modifications only modify a subset of columns, say...

User 1:

```
update MyTable set Col1 = '1', Col2 = '2' where ID = 'abc'
```

User 2:

```
update MyTable set Col2 = 'x', Col3 = 'y' where ID = 'abc'
```

You can be certain that `Col1` will be '1' and `Col3' will be 'y', as those two columns were only updated in one statement. The value of`Col2` will be determined by whichever command executed *last*.

Likewise, if one user updated the row and another user deleted it, then the row would be deleted no matter what. If the update user's command came first, then the update would succeed and the row would then be deleted. If the delete command came first, then the row would first be deleted and the update would not do anything since the row doesn't exist (the `where` clause would not match any rows).

**However**, very few applications actually bother to issue updates to the database with commands that only include changed columns. In almost all applications, commands are created at the table level and they update all columns, then the "current" (changed or not) values are passed into these commands. This is the reason for using optimistic concurrency.

Assuming that row `abc` currently has the values:

```
ID = 'abc'
Col1 = '1_original'
Col2 = '2_original'
Col3 = '3_original'
```

And that both users retrieved the row at the same time, our above commands would more realistically look like this:

User 1:

```
update MyTable set Col1 = '1', Col2 = '2', Col3 = '3_original' where ID = 'abc'
```

User 2:

```
update MyTable set Col1 = '1_original', Col2 = 'x', Col3 = 'y' where ID = 'abc'
```

Now we have a problem; even though our second command really doesn't care about the value in `Col1`, it may overwrite the value that was set by User 1. Likewise, if User 2 hit first, then User 1 would overwrite the value written to `Col3` by User 2.

Optimistic concurrency essentially expands the `where` clause to check the value of *every* column, not just the key of the table. This way you can be sure that you aren't overwriting any changes made by someone (or something) else in the time between when you retrieved a row and when you saved it back.

So, given the same conditions, our commands would look like:

User 1:

```
update MyTable set Col1 = '1', Col2 = '2', Col3 = '3_original' where ID = 'abc' 
        and Col1 = '1_original' and Col2 = '2_original' and Col3 = '3_original'
```

User 2:

```
update MyTable set Col1 = '1_original', Col2 = 'x', Col3 = 'y' where ID = 'abc'
        and Col1 = '1_original' and Col2 = '2_original' and Col3 = '3_original'
```

This means that whichever command hits the database last won't actually do anything, since the columns will no longer have their original values.

Answer (score 5):

The APIs for transactions retry a few times (default 3x, for a total of 4 attempts). Assuming your transactional function does something like read an entity, update a property, write it back, a retry will also re-read etc. So usually you won't notice the failures unless there is heavy contention.

You misread the bit about inserts; usually inserts use different keys so there won't be contention at all. (They would use the same key only if explicitly set the same by the app.)